# Symfony axios pass only id or entire object?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, routes, axios

I have a `Booking` entity which has a ManyToOne relationship with my `Car` entity. I use axios to post my data for creating a `Booking`. I'm not sure if it's better practice to pass my whole `Car` object to my `create` function inside my Controller or to only pass the Car's `id` to the route of the function (which then fetches the Car from my database thanks to Symfonys param converter). Or is there another way which is considered "best practice"?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your scenario and the way you want to use.

Whenever you have to create an object / row inside the database then you will have to pass the whole object. assuming that the cars has already been created inside the database and you only have to link the booking object with the car than i will prefer you to bind it using ids rather than placing the whole object.

If you place the whole car object than it will increase the retrieval performance but if someday the information of car is changed than you will have to change the information on every booking object in which you placed the car object but if you just bind it with the Car Id than it will always give user the latest information even if the info of Car has been changed.

I thought that it will reduce the performance of the application if we used Id but that is not the case the DBMS use indexing to manage the search and search through id takes not time. It performance is not an issue and yes if you pass a whole object than it will also consume more data (since a large amount of data will be uploaded).